# Java convert a HEX String to a BigInt

Tags: java

Hi am trying to convert a hex string such as String hexStr = "1b0ee1e3"; to a bigInt,
ideally i'd like to convert hexStr to a bigint in its decimal form,

I can convert a string to a bigInt w/o issues but when the string contains hex values
i run into problems

Comment: Some of that doesn't make sense. There is no such thing as a 'BigInt in its decimal form'. The form of a BigInt is binary.

Comment: when i pass in a string to a bigint in hex form its converted to its decimal form! try it

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(hexString, 16);
```

For example:

```
import java.math.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hexStr = "1b0ee1e3";
        BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(hexStr, 16);
        System.out.println(bigInt); // Prints 453960163
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, all i was missing was the 16 to declare the input as hex!!,Thanks Jon